# What is TypeScript equivalent of ParentClass.this

Tags: java, typescript

From Java code below. What is the TypeScript equivalent of `ParentClass.this.a`

```java
class ParentClass{
  int a = 1;
  class ChildrenClass{
    int b = 2;
    void run(){
      this.b = ParentClass.this.a;
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to access parent's variable while inside a callback function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such concept in typescript/javascript. In fact you can't just define a class within a class (ie nested classes), the syntax above is not valid typescript.

The closest you can get is to use declaration merging to merge a namespace and a class to get the nested class in the parent class scope, and the pass in the parent class instance:

```
class ParentClass {
    a = 1;
    childClass: ParentClass.ChildrenClass;
    constructor() {
        this.childClass = new ParentClass.ChildrenClass(this);
    }
}
namespace ParentClass {
    export class ChildrenClass {
        constructor(private parentClassThis: ParentClass){}
        b = 2;
        run(): void {
            this.b = this.parentClassThis.a;
        }
    }
}
```